# sbt-native-packager and RPM - how do I set required parameters?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm finding it diffuclt to build a Play project using the sbt native packager. I don't know where to set the RPM configuration when I am given the following error:

```
[error] `rpmVendor in Rpm` is empty.  Please provide a valid vendor for the rpm SPEC.
[error] `packageSummary in Rpm` is empty.  Please provide a valid summary for the rpm SPEC.
[error] `packageDescription in Rpm` is empty.  Please provide a valid description for the rpm SPEC.
```

I've set the following in `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "0.8.0")
```

In my build.sbt:

```
name := """supersecretproject"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  ws  
)

libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.27"

javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.6", "-target", "1.6")

tomcat()
```

The [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/rpm.html) merely states:

> A rpm package needs some mandatory settings to be valid. Make sure you have these settings in your build:

```
rpmRelease := "1"

rpmVendor := "typesafe"

rpmUrl := Some("http://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras")

rpmLicense := Some("BSD")
```

Which is almost entirely useless if you don't know SBT very well! How do I "have these settings in your build:" as the documentation instructs?

I've tried adding the above "settings" to build.sbt or a separate packageSettings.sbt but with no luck as I just get the following error:

```
error: not found: value rpmRelease
rpmRelease := "1"
^
[error] Type error in expression
```

Note: I run the sbt using `sbt rpm:packageBin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the developers of that plugin are trying to not be too prescriptive, but in doing so have not given you enough information to even get started! :-(

**The simplest possible solution:** Copy those four settings (including the blank lines between) into your `build.sbt`.

A logical place is probably towards the bottom of the file, as "packaging" your app is something that happens "towards the end" of the development cycle.

**Another option:** SBT [automatically combines](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Best-Practices.html) the contents of all `.sbt` files it finds in the project root. So if you prefer, you could create a new file such as `packagingSettings.sbt` and put those settings in there.

#### Edit: Help with imports:

Whichever option you choose, you'll need to add the following imports at the top of the file (as per the [getting started guide](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/gettingstarted.html)):

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager._
import NativePackagerKeys._
```

Comment: I'e already tried adding that to the build.sbt and get the following errors: `error: not found: value rpmRelease 
rpmRelease := "1"`

Comment: Note: I run sbt using rpm:packageBin

Comment: After adding the imports and both `packageSummary := ...` and `packageDescription := ...` it worked! Thanks :)